# gvim on windows 7 - vimrun.exe doesn't run command

Tags: vim, windows-7

On a new windows 7 build vim commands don't actually run, but gvim echo's the command attempted to run.

in vim the command `:!dir` opens a vimrun.exe terminal and shows the following:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe --login -c "dir"
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\USERNAME>
```

The window sits like this, until i type `exit` and return control back to vim.

```
C:\Users\USERNAME>exit
Hit any key to close this window...
```

How can i have vim run commands like this on windows 7?  I had no issues on windows xp previously.

It effects multiple programs such as diff.exe and others.

Additional info is it's a recently compiled version of vim with python and ruby support built in.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Dec 18 2013 13:15:06)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
Compiled by J4ROCH@ACEINA
Huge version with GUI.
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--login -c` arguments passed to `cmd.exe` are wrong. It has to be `/c`. Something is changing the `'shellcmdflag'`. Also, that Vim 7.4 version should wrap the `dir` command in parentheses, not quotes, so the `'shellxquote'` flag is off, too.

This is either due to an explicit misconfiguration (in `~/.vimrc`, or by a plugin), or because the various heuristics that Vim uses to detect the correct shell environment fail. Check with

```
:verbose set shell? shellcmdflag? shellxquote?
```

and read `:help 'shell'` to learn more about the heuristics.

Comment: That was exactly it.  I had some invalid things in my _vimrc due to playing with cygwin awhile back.  As i hadn't used diff.exe on a day-to-day basis i thought it had to do with windows 7.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, great! When you "play around" next time, it's better to wrap those attempts in `if has('win32unix')` conditionals (for Cygwin).